# How can I delete an element in the record field?

Tags: list, types, record, sml, ml

I am new to SML and I am learning from the materials I can get on google and stackoverflow.

For fun, I just try to do random stuffs like:

```
type schedule= { transportation:string, go: string list}

val sunday:schedule ={ transportation="Bicycle", go=["gym","walmart","dentist"]}
```

I want to remove the place from my record after I have visited them.

```
fun del("walmart", sunday);=> { transportation="Bicycle", go=["gym","dentist"]}
```

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291683/remove-elements-from-a-list-in-ml/) I know how to delete elements from normal list.
My problem is that I do not know how to access a list in a record and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract values from records using pattern matching. You can perform the changes you need to do, and construct a new record containing the updated values.

For instance, if I had a person record:

```
val john = { name = "John", age = 23, country = "Denmark" }
```

If I then wanted to increment their age, I could do as follows:

```
fun updateAge {name, age, country} = { name = name, age = age + 1, country = country }
val john' = updateAge john
```

So, in short: Extract the fields, delete the element from the list the way you know how to do, and then reconstruct the record.

Comment: ,so I could like extract it with (#go schedule) and pass it to another function called delete, right? Thank you so much.